# Should I assign gid explicitly when I create a group?

Tags: group

I thought `gid` is automatically assigned when I create a group.
But I found a chef receipt file that assigns a number `403` to `gid` directly.
https://github.com/treasure-data/chef-td-agent/blob/master/recipes/default.rb

Does it not cause a overlapping `gid`s?
And what is the reason when you assign a `gid` explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New users typically get assigned at gid 500. You can change this by modifying  `UID_MIN` in /etc/login.def

( Note: Some older distros started at 100, and some new distros made 1000 the default).

Users below the `UID_MIN` are non system users (eg. apache, tomcat, ect..).

The author of the recipe likely piked a random number less than 500 and claimed it for their own purposes. While it is not best practice, it is unlikely another program is hard coded to use 403.

A better approach would have been for the recipe author to set `system = true` at the user creation.

```
user 'td-agent' do
  comment  'td-agent'
  system   true
   ....
end
```

http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html

---

Additional Resources

[What are the dangers of creating a normal user with UID < 500?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101313/what-are-the-dangers-of-creating-a-normal-user-with-uid-500)